# Dependency injection resolution of async factory

Tags: dependency-injection, dart

Having some issues with injecting a database connection into a class via the [di.dart](https://github.com/angular/di.dart) package. Specifically, resolving an async dependency in the `toFactory` option. 
Both attempts result in the

`NoSuchMethodError: Class '_Future' has no instance method 'query'.`

error and it's unclear the correct path forward. I would prefer to keep the `conn` property without being wrapped in a Future. I've attempted doing the unwrapping of the Future in the class constructor but async constructors are not allowed in Dart at this time.

```
import 'package:postgresql/pool.dart';
import 'package:postgresql/postgresql.dart';
import 'package:di/di.dart';

main() async {
  var uri = "postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/database";
  var pool = new Pool(uri, minConnections: 2, maxConnections: 5);
  await pool.start();

  Module module = new Module();
  module.bind(TestQuery);
  module.bind(TestController);
  module.bind(Pool, toValue: pool);
  module.bind(Connection, toFactory: (pool) => pool.connect(), inject: [Pool]);

  var injector = new ModuleInjector([module]);

  var html = await injector.get(TestController).index(); 
  print(html);
}

class BaseQuery {
  Connection conn;

  BaseQuery(Connection this.conn);
}

class TestQuery extends BaseQuery {
  TestQuery(Connection conn) : super(conn); // type '_Future' is not a subtype of type 'Connection' of 'conn' where

  run() async {
    var results =  await conn.query("select 1").toList();

    // Do some data manipulation

    return results;
  }
}

class TestController {
  TestQuery testQuery;

  TestController(TestQuery this.testQuery);

  index() async {
    var results = await testQuery.run();

    var html = "<pre>" + results.toString() + "</pre>";

    return html;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce but when I change the line to

```
var conn = await injector.get(Connection);
var res = await conn.query("select 1").toList();
```

it working fine.

I think your code should work as well though.

Comment: That's more or less the same as the "res1" example I left. What I can't figure out is how to get the async Connection dependency into the Query class.

Comment: Sure, but this way it didn't cause an error, while the single line code did.

Comment: This was a simplified example to illustrate my problem. In reality, there's a Controller class that accepts a Query in it's constructor and the Query class does significantly more than just execute the single line of code.
Unwrapping the future that is returned from `injector.get(Connection)` cannot be done in the constructor of Query (because it's async). It also cannot be done in `main()` due to the issues with async in `toFactory:`.
I'm curious if there's a technique that I don't know of for unwrapping the future within `toFactory:` so that the resolved `Connection` can be passed thru DI.

Comment: If it helps, I could edit my question to include a more complete example

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the problem. With your code I could reproduce your error, and when I changed it like in my answrr the error was gone. The code is basically the same, just a bit more verbose but the error was gone.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't think I initially explained my issue very clearly. I've included a more comprehensive example that should help

Comment: I'll have another look tomorrow